# Optimizing a large MySQL table - Partitioning?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

My columns are:

`job_name, job_date, job_details1, job_details2 ...`

There are NO Primary key columns

In my table, I expect to have 15-20 distinct jobs. Each job with exactly 2 months of data so 60 distinct `job_date` per `job_name`. And within each date there would be `100,000` records.

Query will always be a SELECT for ONE particular `job_name` and a range of `job_date` (followed by several group bys, but that's irrelevant for now). I don't want the query to go through irrelevant `job_date`s or `job_name`s when queried for a particular `job_name` and some range of `job_date`.

So what sort of optimizations can I do to make my select query faster? I'm using MySQL5.6.17, which has a partitioning limit of 8096 partitions.

Something like partitioning per `job_name` and subpartitions for `job_date` within that? This is the first time I'm dealing with such large data so I'm not sure about these optimizations. Any help or tips will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "*There are NO Primary key columns*" - really? How would you ever retrieve a single row if you have no unique key? 2 months of data with 100.000 rows per date yields a total of approx. 6 million rows. Hardly considered large nowadays. Why do you think you need to partition that? How does your query look like? What indexes do you have? What is the execution plan?

Comment: Why would you assume that I need to retrieve single rows? All my queries will be aggregate operations using several group bys. I've mentioned exactly what my query will look like in my question.
I need to partition it because my operations will always be on ONE job_name over a range of job_date; and I woudn't want my query to look over irrelavant data of other job_name or job_date outside of the specified range.

Comment: While you might have "mentioned" what your query looks like you did not show us the actual query. If your queries all contain something like `where job_name = 'foo'` a simple index on that column will probably do the job.

Answer (score 0):

"Query will always be a SELECT for ONE particular job_name and a range of job_date (followed by several group bys, but that's irrelevant for now)." -- Based on that, you need

```
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(job_name, job_date, id),
INDEX(id)
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Notes:

- The combination of InnoDB with `PK(job_name, job_date, ...) clusters the data so that you scan *exactly* the rows you need, and *nothing* more.
- No partitioning; it won't help.
- I am adding an `AUTO_INCREMENT` and adding it to the PK because a PK *must* be unique.  (And the PK is needed for the clustering.)
- `INDEX(id)` (or some key *starting* with `id`) is needed for `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

"... followed by group bys ..."  That sounds like you are summarizing data for reports?  If my suggestions above are not fast enough, let's talk about [Summary Tables](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).  You might get another factor of 10 speedup.